# git push to Heroku is rejected

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Even though I'm doing a clean build

```
heroku repo:purge_cache -a redrum-js-client
```

Git push to Heroku fails with

```
Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Full log file is [here](https://bitbucket.org/redrum-nodejs/redrum-js-client/downloads/heroku_build_failure.txt)

Really appreciate if you have any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have an idea why this is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding nodejs and npm version fixed the problem.

```
"engines": {
"node": "0.12.7",
"npm": "2.14.4"
```

}